# htaccess regex not accepting some special characters

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a PHP script located at `http://localhost/dir1/dir2/shift.php` that I am passing urls as parameters to like so: `http://localhost/dir1/dir2/https://google.com` but I am getting a Forbidden you don't have access error. When I remove the `:` it works fine though. I have checked my regex with some online regex validation tools and it says that it should be working but it doesn't

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^dir1\/dir2\/([A-Za-z0-9\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\_\-\+\=\{\}\[\]\;\:\'\"\<\,\>\.\?\|\~\`\s\/\\]+)\/?  dir1\/dir2\/shift.php?url=$1 [L]
```

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: That pattern is using some \u\n\n\e\c\e\s\s\a\r\y \e\s\c\a\p\i\n\g in the character class.

Comment: You can use something like regex101 to doublecheck the regex? Looks overly complicated to me though.

Comment: Be careful of reserved characters.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/1547899/2943403  urls have rules -- not just which characters can be used, but _where_ they can be used.  Your desired url seems _weird_ to me.

Comment: This is my first time really dealing with regex so I'm still learning. I did try regex101 and it said its valid. Basically I am trying just to pass everything after `dir1/dir2/` as a parameter to shift.php. The PHP script will handle validating the url.

Comment: `:` can lead to errors in url2filesystem mapping as forbidden symbol. This should work in non-directory context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **should not** use reserved characters in URL.

Though you can URL encode and then pass it as a parameter. For example:

```
http://localhost/dir1/dir2/shift.php?
param=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fdir1%2Fdir2%2Fhttps%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com
```

And then in `shift.php` you can first URL decode the parameter and then use.